# Opendaylight Can't Connect to HP Aruba SDN Switch

Tags: sdn, opendaylight

My lab recently procure an HP (Aruba) 2920 24G and I was told to test it out on an OpenDaylight controller.

First, I setup the OpenDaylight Carbon (0.7.2) with dlux features, odl-mdsal-apidocs, odl-restconf, and odl-l2switch-switch installed. The Opendaylight can communicate with my other switches including an SBC running an Open vSwitch, a mininet, Zodiac FX SDN switches, and a Pica8 Switch, but strangely, not with the mentioned HP SDN switch.

I decided to try the HP switch with Opendaylight Hydrogen (the first one), and it worked just fine (though it forced the controller to communicate with OpenFlow 1.0). But I seemed can't make it work with Opendaylight version other than hydrogen (I tried with Carbon, Nitrogen, and Oxygen).

How can I connect that switch, is there anything that I should do before I enable Openflow? Any hints or helps will be appreciated.

Thanks

Here is the TCP dump of my controller

```css
listening on ens3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
05:40:22.762385 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [S], seq 3953235407, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 1,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,nop,TS val 670643980 ecr 0], length 0
05:40:22.762979 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [S.], seq 1719626668, ack 3953235408, win 28960, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2130420 ecr 670643980,nop,wscale 7], length 0
05:40:22.766268 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [.], ack 1, win 33304, options [nop,nop,TS val 670643980 ecr 2130420], length 0
05:40:22.766515 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1:17, ack 1, win 33304, options [nop,nop,TS val 670643980 ecr 2130420], length 16: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x00, length 16, xid 0x00000154
05:40:22.766559 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 17, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2130421 ecr 670643980], length 0
05:40:23.038345 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 1:25, ack 17, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2130489 ecr 670643980], length 24: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x00, length 16, xid 0x00000015
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x05, length 8, xid 0x00000155
05:40:23.241617 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 1:25, ack 17, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2130540 ecr 670643980], length 24: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x00, length 16, xid 0x00000015
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x05, length 8, xid 0x00000155
05:40:23.247591 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [.], ack 25, win 33292, options [nop,nop,TS val 670644460 ecr 2130489], length 0
05:40:23.247941 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 17:49, ack 25, win 33292, options [nop,nop,TS val 670644460 ecr 2130489], length 32: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x06, length 32, xid 0x00000155
05:40:23.248228 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 49, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2130541 ecr 670644460], length 0
05:40:23.248247 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [.], ack 25, win 33292, options [nop,nop,TS val 670644460 ecr 2130540], length 0
05:40:23.297400 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 25:33, ack 49, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2130554 ecr 670644460], length 8: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x14, length 8, xid 0x00000000
05:40:23.299582 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 49:57, ack 33, win 33288, options [nop,nop,TS val 670644520 ecr 2130554], length 8: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x15, length 8, xid 0x00000000
05:40:23.299724 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 57, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2130554 ecr 670644520], length 0
05:40:23.854453 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 33:49, ack 57, win 227, options [nop,nop,TS val 2130693 ecr 670644520], length 16: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 16, xid 0x00000000
05:40:23.858279 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 57:1129, ack 49, win 33280, options [nop,nop,TS val 670645070 ecr 2130693], length 1072: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 1072, xid 0x00000000
05:40:23.858532 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 1129, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 2130694 ecr 670645070], length 0
05:40:25.303081 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 49:97, ack 1129, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131055 ecr 670645070], length 48: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 16, xid 0x00000001
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 16, xid 0x00000002
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 16, xid 0x00000003
05:40:25.306476 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 97:105, ack 1129, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131056 ecr 670645070], length 8: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x14, length 8, xid 0x00000004
05:40:25.307288 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1129:1161, ack 97, win 33256, options [nop,nop,TS val 670646520 ecr 2131055], length 32: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 32, xid 0x00000001
05:40:25.307606 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 1161, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131056 ecr 670646520], length 0
05:40:25.307650 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1161:1217, ack 97, win 33256, options [nop,nop,TS val 670646520 ecr 2131055], length 56: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 56, xid 0x00000002
05:40:25.307686 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 1217, win 243, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131056 ecr 670646520], length 0
05:40:25.307714 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1217:1553, ack 97, win 33256, options [nop,nop,TS val 670646520 ecr 2131055], length 336: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 336, xid 0x00000003
05:40:25.307732 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 1553, win 260, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131056 ecr 670646520], length 0
05:40:25.308882 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1553:1561, ack 105, win 33252, options [nop,nop,TS val 670646530 ecr 2131056], length 8: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x15, length 8, xid 0x00000004
05:40:25.308989 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 1561, win 260, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131056 ecr 670646530], length 0
05:40:26.528768 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 105:121, ack 1561, win 260, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131361 ecr 670646530], length 16: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 16, xid 0x00000005
05:40:26.531364 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1561:1649, ack 121, win 33244, options [nop,nop,TS val 670647750 ecr 2131361], length 88: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 88, xid 0x00000005
05:40:26.531491 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 1649, win 260, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131362 ecr 670647750], length 0
05:40:26.616425 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 121:145, ack 1649, win 260, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131383 ecr 670647750], length 24: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x18, length 24, xid 0x00000006
05:40:26.618757 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1649:1673, ack 145, win 33232, options [nop,nop,TS val 670647840 ecr 2131383], length 24: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x19, length 24, xid 0x00000006
05:40:26.618815 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 1673, win 260, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131384 ecr 670647840], length 0
05:40:26.634375 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 145:169, ack 1673, win 260, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131388 ecr 670647840], length 24: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x18, length 24, xid 0x00000007
05:40:26.636584 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1673:1697, ack 169, win 33220, options [nop,nop,TS val 670647850 ecr 2131388], length 24: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x19, length 24, xid 0x00000007
05:40:26.673259 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 1697, win 260, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131398 ecr 670647850], length 0
05:40:26.757717 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 169:225, ack 1697, win 260, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131419 ecr 670647850], length 56: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 56, xid 0x00000008
05:40:26.760788 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1697:1889, ack 225, win 33192, options [nop,nop,TS val 670647980 ecr 2131419], length 192: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 192, xid 0x00000008
05:40:26.761396 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 1889, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131420 ecr 670647980], length 0
05:40:27.341945 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 225:233, ack 1889, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131565 ecr 670647980], length 8: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x14, length 8, xid 0x00000009
05:40:27.344842 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1889:1897, ack 233, win 33188, options [nop,nop,TS val 670648560 ecr 2131565], length 8: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x15, length 8, xid 0x00000009
05:40:27.344983 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 1897, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131565 ecr 670648560], length 0
05:40:27.353082 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 233:249, ack 1897, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131567 ecr 670648560], length 16: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 16, xid 0x0000000a
05:40:27.355175 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1897:1913, ack 249, win 33180, options [nop,nop,TS val 670648570 ecr 2131567], length 16: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 16, xid 0x0000000a
05:40:27.368322 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 249:273, ack 1913, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131571 ecr 670648570], length 24: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 24, xid 0x0000000b
05:40:27.370344 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1913:1929, ack 273, win 33168, options [nop,nop,TS val 670648590 ecr 2131571], length 16: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 16, xid 0x0000000b
05:40:27.379058 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 273:297, ack 1929, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131574 ecr 670648590], length 24: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 24, xid 0x0000000c
05:40:27.381262 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1929:1945, ack 297, win 33156, options [nop,nop,TS val 670648600 ecr 2131574], length 16: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 16, xid 0x0000000c
05:40:27.392610 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 297:321, ack 1945, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131577 ecr 670648600], length 24: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 24, xid 0x0000000d
05:40:27.394715 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1945:1961, ack 321, win 33144, options [nop,nop,TS val 670648610 ecr 2131577], length 16: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 16, xid 0x0000000d
05:40:27.415032 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 321:345, ack 1961, win 277, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131583 ecr 670648610], length 24: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x12, length 24, xid 0x0000000e
05:40:27.417823 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 1961:2537, ack 345, win 33132, options [nop,nop,TS val 670648640 ecr 2131583], length 576: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x13, length 576, xid 0x0000000e
05:40:27.457328 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 2537, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131594 ecr 670648640], length 0
05:40:27.854786 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [P.], seq 345:353, ack 2537, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131693 ecr 670648640], length 8: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x14, length 8, xid 0x0000000f
05:40:27.856998 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [P.], seq 2537:2545, ack 353, win 33128, options [nop,nop,TS val 670649070 ecr 2131693], length 8: OpenFlow
        version unknown (0x04), type 0x15, length 8, xid 0x0000000f
05:40:27.857080 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 2545, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131693 ecr 670649070], length 0
05:40:28.077260 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [F.], seq 353, ack 2545, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131748 ecr 670649070], length 0
05:40:28.080095 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [.], ack 354, win 33127, options [nop,nop,TS val 670649300 ecr 2131748], length 0
05:40:28.080717 IP 10.10.5.91.61524 > 10.10.5.101.6633: Flags [FP.], seq 2545, ack 354, win 33127, options [nop,nop,TS val 670649300 ecr 2131748], length 0
05:40:28.081006 IP 10.10.5.101.6633 > 10.10.5.91.61524: Flags [.], ack 2546, win 294, options [nop,nop,TS val 2131749 ecr 670649300], length 0
```

Answer (score 1):

someone else recently made a post about HP switches not connecting to ODL, but
I cannot find that post to reference?

I would check the switch logs. the packet capture seems to indicate there is
some communication between the switch and controller:6633.

you can also look for clues in OpenDaylight's karaf.log file

at the end of the day, since your other switches are connecting fine you
probably will have to find HP switch support, more-so that OpenDaylight
support.

Comment: Yes, I also found that question, a few days ago which was deleted but could still be accessed by google cache. The username is darcn. I will try to contact that person.

In the meantime I'll check the log file, thank you very much